# Running 2 separate ELK stacks on docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

On my AWS EC2 linux server I'am running one ELK stack, where logstash is transforming postgress database and importing into Elasticsearch. This setup is currently in use for my development environment. We have come to a point where we created staging environment and so we also need probably a separate ELK stack for staging, since we don't want to mix the data from 2 separate databases (dev and stage).

I have quite minor experience in ELK, I have checked some options but did not find any solution to this problem.

What I have tried is to create another `docker-compose` file with different container names and ports. When I run `docker-compose.elastic.dev.yml` it normally creates first ELK stack. Then I run `docker-compose.elastic.stage.yml` but it starts to `recreate` existing ELK containers. I have tried to play with docker-compose settings but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Just for reference, kibana is not included in dev, because we dont need it there.

**docker-compose.elastic.stage.yml**

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch-stage:
    container_name: elasticsearch-stage
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    ports:
      - 9400:9200
    environment:
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.cors.allow-methods=OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
      - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data_stage:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - api_network
  kibana-stage:
    container_name: kibana-stage
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - api_network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-stage
  logstash-stage:
    container_name: logstash-stage
    ports:
      - 5045:5045
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.logstash
      context: .
    environment:
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://serverip:15433/name"
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME: "name"
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD: "password"
      LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: "http://elasticsearch-stage:9200"
    volumes:
      - ./logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
      - ./offers_template.json:/usr/share/logstash/templates/offers_template.json
      - ./offers_query.sql:/usr/share/logstash/queries/offers_query.sql
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200m"
        max-file: "5"
    networks:
      - api_network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-stage
      - kibana-stage
volumes:
  elasticsearch_data_stage:
networks:
  api_network:
    name: name_api_network_stage
```

**docker-compose.elastic.dev.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.cors.allow-methods=OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
      - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - api_network
  logstash:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.logstash
      context: .
    environment:
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://serverip:15432/username"
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME: "username"
      LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD: "password"
      LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
    volumes:
      - ./logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
      - ./offers_template.json:/usr/share/logstash/templates/offers_template.json
      - ./offers_query.sql:/usr/share/logstash/queries/offers_query.sql
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200m"
        max-file: "5"
    networks:
      - api_network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
volumes:
  elasticsearch_data:
networks:
  api_network:
    name: name_api_network
```

I have also found [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mapping-elasticsearch-port-with-ports-92xx-9200-in-docker/133359) article and seems like is similar/same problem, unfortunately topic was closed without confirmed solution.

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/postgresql.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL}"
        jdbc_user => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME}"
        jdbc_password => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD}"
        lowercase_column_names => false
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement_filepath => "/usr/share/logstash/queries/offers_query.sql"
    }
}
filter {
    json {
        source => "name"
        target => "name"
    }
    json {
        source => "description"
        target => "description"
    }
    ...
    ...
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
        index => "offers"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        manage_template => true
        template_name => "offers"
        template => "/usr/share/logstash/templates/offers_template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
    stdout { codec => json_lines }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I found out in [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-outputs-elasticsearch-is-trying-to-connect-to-another-elasticsearch/101526/5), that if not running default logstash configuration, I need to set `XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: "false"` for logstash `environment` and the error from logstash not being able to connect to elasticsearch was gone, but still logstash did not do its job of processing data from the DB as it normally should. What's happening now is in logstash logs, every few minutes there is just plain query text loaded from the `offers_query.sql`. When I enter `elasticsearch_server_ip:9400` I get this output (so it should be running):

```
{
  "name" : "30ac276f0846",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "14mxQTP7S32o-rIrjYSsXw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand you still have the same names of services in files and that is making `docker-compose up -d` confused.

Your problem is the naming of services inside of the docker-compose file.

```
services:
  elasticsearch
  logstash
```

It's the same on dev and staging compose, and since you are not running swarm you will need following:
Separate docker-composes to different folders so docker-compose can create different container names.

And yes, you can't have the same ports on the host port forwarded

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

One elastic search should have 9400:9200 or something similar.

Comment: I have added files, note that dev file has no container names and when they start, they get default names, but staging have names but they recreate dev containers anyways..

Comment: @JMP thanks for the information, I know how much I need it, I just wrote for information..

Comment: Thanks, containers running but logstash cant connect to elasticsearch, because I got the ports wrong I suppose. I have edited my post to the current version of the staging compose file, dev compose is unchanged, please have a look.

Comment: Try to set up the logstash environment to staging to      LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: "http://elasticsearch-stage:9200"  

Why ? .. Left side of the port is the port of your host machine so if you hit localhost:9400 you will get forwarded to container elasticsearch-stage:9200 ... you haven't changed the port of elastic listening to.

Comment: changed it to `elasticsearch-stage:9200` but now getting this error `[2021-09-09T12:38:47,445][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
`

Comment: Are you sure? The error says "http://elasticsearch:9200/", you should have elasticsearch-staging .. Is it maybe in your config?

Comment: Which config? All files regarding ELK stack are: `Dockerfile.logstash, docker-compose.elastic.stage.yml, logstash.conf, offers_query.sql, offers_template.json and postgresql-42.2.8.jar` And I have added `logstash.conf` to my question but there should be everything okay. Maybe I was thinking if it doesnt read some configurations from the dev ELK instance, where I have `elasticsearch:9200`.

Comment: I have also added some new information to my question, please have a look. At this point, there is problem with logstash doing its job, but not sure if disabling xpack monitoring made it worse or not.

Comment: You  have 2 outputs in the config, one is elastic search and another one is stout (terminal), so my guess it's working, now try to hit 
`http://elasticsearch_server_ip:9400/_cat/indices`  and you should see offers index inside..

Btw I am not sure about your Kibana configs on staging but you can add environment variable to your config file `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://elasticsearch-stage:9200`

Comment: Yes, I let it sit for a while and there is over 1GB of data in database, so it took a while to load into logstash and process, I got only 4GB on AWS EC2 currently, so .. And about Kibana, you mean how I have configured kibana to load stuff from elasticsearch? I dont because I don't know how to do it just yet. I will set the config you suggested and see how it goes, if I struggle, I will add into my question this setup.